# Android 8 encrypt phone vs SD card

Tags: encryption

I have Android 8.1 on my phone.
It states under Settings->Security->Encryption&cred = Phone Encrypted.

I am using microSD on my phone. This microSD is not encrypted as I am able to remove it and read it.

Does Android 8.1 have capability to encrypt microSD card?
If so, where would I find this option? Do all phone manufactures implement this option?

Comment: capability to encrypt means the MicroSD Card will not be longer removeable, and data is not recoverable for damaged MicroSD Cards (because encryption key is not accessable/shareable) [\[adoptable-storage\]](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)